# How to implement oauth2orize new exchange policy for mobile number and security pin

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, oauth2orize

How to implement custom exchange policy.

I want to generate token for mobile number and security pin
like client password strategies

Comment: Could you be more specific in what are you trying to achieve? The OAuth spec does not contain anything about exchanging mobile numbers. Perhaphs are you trying to adapt the standard client credentials flow to use mobile numbers instead of client id and secret.